# How can I determine this linear transformation?

Tags: linear-transformations

> Let $a,b \in \mathbb R$, $a<b$ and let $f(x)=\sin^{-1}(x)$. Determine
>   a linear transformation $g: \mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$, 
>   $x\mapsto z_1x+z_0$ such that $g([a,b])=[-1,1]$. Specify the inverse
>   function $g^{-1}$ and plot $f(g(x))$ where $x \in \mathbb [a,b]$.

I am not sure which transformation I am looking for here. My best guess is that this is referring to **integration**:

$$g[x]= \int dz [x]=z_1x+z_0$$

However, I am unsure how to interpret the statement that $g([a,b])=[-1,1]$. Would that mean that the definite integral from $a$ to $b$ would yield an area between $-1$ and $1$. Is integration even the correct transformation I am looking for here?

Comment: Usually $f([a,b])=\{f(x)|x \in [a,b]\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $g(x)=\dfrac{2x}{b-a}-\dfrac{a+b}{b-a}$. It is clear that:

- $g(a)=-1$;
- $g(b)=1$;
- $g(x)$ is of the form $z_1x+z_0$.

In fact, I computed $z_1$ and $z_0$ by solving the system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}z_1a+z_0=-1\\z_1b+z_0=1.\end{array}\right.$$So, $g$ is the function that you're after.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That was actually much easier than all the things I tried to do. I have a follow up questions regarding the notation $g: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$. That means that the transformation takes a real number and the output is also a real number right? Let's assume the transformation had taken a one-dimensional subspace of an $n-$dimensional vector space as an input. Would the notation still be $g:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ or would the notation be  $\mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$?

Comment: Neither is correct. Let $V$ be the one-dimensional subspace that you mentioned. THen the notation would ne $g\colon V\longrightarrow\mathbb R$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and thank you again for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

If $g(z)=z_0+z_1x$, then $g$ is indeed affine but not linear (if $z_0\neq 0$). Anyway, if $g(z)=z_0+z_1x$ with $z_1\neq 0$, then $g$ is strictly monotone. i.e. $$g([a,b])=[-1,1]\iff \begin{cases}z_0+az_1=-1\text{ and }z_0+z_1b=1\\ \text{or}\\ z_0+az_1=1\text{ and }z_0+bz_1=-1\end{cases}.$$

Comment: I hope this isn't a stupid question but what exactly is the difference betwen an affine and a linear transformation? I thought affine transformations are sort of a subset of linear transformations.

Comment: A linear application is additive, i.e. $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ and homogeneous, i.e. $f(\lambda x)=\lambda f(x)$. An affine application is a linear application up to translation, i.e. $g$ is affine if there is a translation $\tau$ and a linear application $f$ s.t. $g=\tau\circ f\circ \tau^{-1}$. In particular, linear application are affine, but the converse is not true. In other word, affine application are of the form $g(x)=Ax+v$ @qmd

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you very much for your help.